# How to create a Dataset from Nested JSON Data?

Tags: import, dataset, json-format

I'm importing data from [Swarm](https://www.swarmpapp.com) into Mathematica, and I'm trying to create a dataset and having issues because the values are at different levels:

```
$.venue.name
$.venue.location.address
$.venue.location.city
$.venue.location.state
$.venue.location.postalCode
$.venue.location.lat
$.venue.location.lng
```

I have this:

```
checkinData[All, "venue", "location", {"address", "city", "state", "postalCode", "lat", "lng"}]
```

which provides everything but that first column that's at a higher level.  How do I get that higher-level column in?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by asking "How do I get that higher-level column in?". In what? How do you want it represented? You could just do this: `checkinData[All, "venue", {"name", "location"}]` and you'll get results that include all of the location components. But I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: Almost there. What I need is to create a dataset where each row consists of venue.name, venue.location.lat, venue.location.lng.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the functionality you seek can be found in the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) functions [`ResourceFunction["ToAssociations"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToAssociations) and [`ResourceFunction["AssociationKeyFlatten"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AssociationKeyFlatten/).

With

```
json=ImportString[
 "{
   \"Venue\":{\"Name\":\"ABC\",\"Location\":{\"L1\":\"DEF\",\"L2\":\"GHI\"}}
   ,\"Venue\":{\"Name\":\"JKL\",\"Location\":{\"L1\":\"MNO\",\"L2\":\"PQR\"}}
  }"
 ,"JSON"
 ];
```

Then

```
flatJson =
 Map[
  KeyMap[StringRiffle[#, "."] &]
  , Map[
   ResourceFunction["AssociationKeyFlatten"]
   , ResourceFunction["ToAssociations"]@Map[List, json]
   ]
  ]
```

> ```
> {<|"Venue.Name" -> "ABC", "Venue.Location.L1" -> "DEF", "Venue.Location.L2" -> "GHI"|>
>  , <|"Venue.Name" -> "JKL", "Venue.Location.L1" -> "MNO", "Venue.Location.L2" -> "PQR"|>}
> ```

and

```
Dataset[flatJson]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I like your answer better than my own. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but I got it to work by creating a new Table with the required data points:

```
url = StringTemplate[
    "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?afterTimestamp=\
`a`&oauth_token=`b`&limit=250&v=20220406"][<|"a" -> startTime, 
    "b" -> oauthToken|>];
checkins = 
  Import[url, "RawJSON"][["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]];
venues = 
  Table[Association["name" -> checkins[[i]][["venue"]][["name"]], 
    "lat" -> 
     GeoPosition[{checkins[[i]][["venue"]][["location"]][["lat"]], 
       checkins[[i]][["venue"]][["location"]][["lng"]]}]], {i, 
    Length[checkins]}];
```